# Ethereum Wallet starts up really slow and loses previously created contracts - private.net

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I created a private test chain using **geth:v1.6.6** and **Wallet:0.9.0.1884**

I used the link for *Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-9-0.zip*

versions 0.8.5 and earlier open in at most 20 seconds where as this version takes around 5 minutes to open.

- 2-3 mins with Loading client config...
- 2-3 mins with Downloading new
  node

I don't see anything specific in fiddler so it looks like its doing nothing or failing at whatever its trying to do and timing out.

Additionally, after I deploy a contract/token, if I restart nothing remains.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you're running a private network? are you sure the wallet is connecting to the private network?

Comment: @Sepultura yes. Only 2 nodes connected and they are all mine. Discover is off. I can see the tx hashes on geth console and use the contract methods from the wallet just fine.

Comment: how do you deploy your contract?

Comment: @Sepultura Via the deploy contracts screen of the wallet. I have to give a little bit more gas than maximum because contract doesnt get stored otherwise.